# What is the [pure] tag for?

Tags: support, tags, burninate-request

What is the [pure](/questions/tagged/pure) tag for? It looks like a candidate for burnination - touches:

- [Pure JavaScript Templates System](http://beebole.com/pure/)
- [Pure Virtual Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions)
- [Pure Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) ()
- [Purely Functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional) functions/algorithms/procedures
- "Pure Pointer Notation"
- A variety of Haskall concepts I don't understand
- C++ `pure_assert_impl`
- The C# [PureAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute.aspx), used in code contracts
- C++ `pure/const`
- Recently I've seen new questions coming in about [Pure Data](http://puredata.info/)
- No mention of [Pure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_%28programming_language%29) that I can find

Seems like an incohesive mess.

---

Is [purity](/questions/tagged/purity) in the same ballpark? (only 7 questions...)

Comment: Before y'all bring out your bazookas, **there is a [legitimate use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_(programming_language)) for the [tag:pure] tag**

Comment: Languages with odd names tend to get tags ending in "lang".  `pure-lang` is probably the best thing to retag relevant questions with.

Comment: @Lorem: any actual questions that use this tag in that context?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't know; I'm not going tag diving now. Just leaving a hint/warning for those that want to...

Comment: @LoremIpsum - So far I'm seeing more of the [Pure HTML/JSON templating framework](http://beebole.com/pure/) than I am of that language.

Answer (score 5):

I've gone through more than half of the questions formerly tagged [pure](/questions/tagged/pure), removing the label when it was clearly not necessary:

- Thinigs like "pure HTML", "pure CSS", "pure JS", "pure Java", "pure Python", "pure Lua" I just removed it.
- In instances of "pure virtual" questions, I changed it to [pure-virtual](/questions/tagged/pure-virtual)

I took a chance and changed some tags from [pure](/questions/tagged/pure) to either [pure-function](/questions/tagged/pure-function) or [purely-functional](/questions/tagged/purely-functional). In some instances of questions about Fortran I changed it to [pure-procedure](/questions/tagged/pure-procedure) and left a comment asking if my change makes sense.

I left several questions as-is, as I didn't feel I knew enough about the following topics (or technologies) to edit them:

- The Pure HTML/JSON templating system
- The Pure programming language
- "Pure pointer notation"
- Haskall concepts: "Pure Functional Programming"; "Pure Global Variable"; "Pure Computation"
- The "Pure Java API" - is this a thing?
- C++ `pure_assert_impl`
- C# Pure code contracts
- C++ pure/const

Answer (score 4):

It is mostly being used as a meta tag:

- Requesting a 'pure' CSS/HTML/Java/C/Lua/whatever solution. ([How do I show two images with different height/width ratios side by side with equal heights, in fluid div that covers percentage of window width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167435/how-do-i-show-two-images-with-different-height-width-ratios-side-by-side-with-eq), [Array access via double pointer, losing its body, pure C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367758/array-access-via-double-pointer-losing-its-body-pure-c),  and more).
- Asking if their approach is 'pure' enough ([What happens if you compile a program that takes no input? (Haskell IO purity issues (again))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382485/what-happens-if-you-compile-a-program-that-takes-no-input-haskell-io-purity-is), [How to represent tree with sharing in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411755/how-to-represent-tree-with-sharing-in-haskell)).

But there is some non-meta use as well:

- About the 'purity' of a functional approach ([Why is printf() an impure function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919894/why-is-printf-an-impure-function), [Why is numCapabilities a pure function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851005/why-is-numcapabilities-a-pure-function), etc.)
  These should be retagged as [purely-functional](/questions/tagged/purely-functional).

If you retag the questions in that last category, *then* you should burn it.

Comment: .Net has a `[Pure]` annotation as a code contract, the language `D` has a `pure` keyword and wikipedia recognizes "pure virtual functions" as a C++ concept. Those are non-meta as well, I think.

Comment: Not sure if all those deserve a tag though; if there are dedicated tags for them, use those instead, otherwise just remove the `pure` tag from those.

Comment: @madth3 - Then perhaps less generic (and less mistakable) tags are needed - [tag:pure-virtual-functions] for example, instead of just [tag:pure]

Comment: Edited the question in category #2

Comment: Looks like there's already a [tag:pure-virtual] tag meant for pure virtual functions.